# How can I get my screenshots out of my Switch, without posting them to social media or using a memory card?

Tags: nintendo-switch

The Switch has a screenshot button and lets me take lots of awesome screenshots. But there doesn't seem to be any way to move them off of the device, other than posting them to Twitter/Facebook.

Is there any way to do this? Ideally without using a flash card? (As that would involve also acquiring a reader for said card for my computer... it's 2017, let me email them!)

Comment: Totally misread the question - excuse my poor deleted answer.  I'm going to say there is no other way besides what you've said.

Comment: Can you send messages with pictures to friends? The way I do this on PS4 is I have an alt account that I send pictures I want to export and then use the phone app to save them to my device from that message thread. Not sure if this is possible on the Switch.

Comment: Sadly it seems like it can be done ... but with a SD card http://www.imore.com/how-take-screenshot-your-nintendo-switch

Answer (score 1):

As you feared it, you will need an SD card to transfer your screenshot from your Switch directly on your computer.

So I'm still going to give you the [link](http://www.imore.com/how-take-screenshot-your-nintendo-switch) explaining how it is done, even if you wished to do it another way.

After, I'm not a pro with social medias, but wouldn't you be able to send them to a fake account where only you would be able to see them or to a friend who would then save them for you ?

Whitout using an SD card, it seems like it's the only thing you can do to obtain those screenshots.